# Flash-like glow filter on 2d Texture in XNA

Tags: c#, filter, xna, texture2d, glow

I'm wondering how I would be able to apply a "glow filter" similar to ones I've seen done in Flash, using the XNA framework.

Here is an example of what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

Which would have been applied using the following code in ActionScript 3:

```
var glow:GlowFilter = new GlowFilter(0xFFCC00, 1.2, 12, 12, 1, 3);
target.filters = [glow];
```

Is there something similar in XNA?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That image is about as wide as my thumb on my monitor. Do you have a larger one so we can see what you are talking about? However, I'm guessing you want something along this line http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/bloom?

Comment: Cant get a bigger image and also, I think that could work, but it wouldnt for windows phone would it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a Shader.

[Here is an old example](http://forum.dead-code.org/index.php?topic=3879.0)